# How can I merge files on a line by line basis?

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, perl, awk

cat file1

```
foo
ice
two
```

cat file2

```
bar
cream
hundred
```

Desired output:

```
foobar
icecream
twohundred
```

file1 and file2 will always have the same amount of lines in my scenario, in case that makes things easier.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The right tool for this job is probably `paste`

```
paste -d '' file1 file2
```

See `man paste` for details.

---

You could also use the `pr` command:

```
pr -TmJS"" file1 file2
```

where

- `-T` turns off pagination
- `-mJ` **m**erge files, **J**oining full lines
- `-S""` separate the columns with an empty string

---

If you *really* wanted to do it using pure bash shell (not recommended), then this is what I'd suggest:

```
while IFS= read -u3 -r a && IFS= read -u4 -r b; do 
  printf '%s%s\n' "$a" "$b"
done 3<file1 4<file2
```

(Only including this because the subject came up in comments to another proposed pure-bash solution.)

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the very simple solution.
Should I ever worry about portability when it comes to using paste?

Comment: @user264974 paste is in GNU Coreutils so you're probably fairly safe.

Answer (score 9):

Through [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) way:

```bsh
awk '{getline x<"file2"; print $0x}' file1
```

- `getline x<"file2"` reads the entire line from *file2* and holds into **x** variable.
- `print $0x` prints the whole line from *file1* by using `$0` then `x` which is the saved line of *file2*.

Comment: Very good to have an awk alternative, I may use this instead!

Answer (score 4):

[`paste` is the way to go](https://askubuntu.com/a/616170/216503). If you want to check some other methods, here is a `python` solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import itertools
with open('/path/to/file1') as f1, open('/path/to/file2') as f2:
    lines = itertools.izip_longest(f1, f2)
    for a, b in lines:
        if a and b:
            print a.rstrip() + b.rstrip()
        else:
            if a:
                print a.rstrip()
            else:
                print b.rstrip()
```

If you have few number of lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('/path/to/file1') as f1, open('/path/to/file2') as f2:
    print '\n'.join((a.rstrip() + b.rstrip() for a, b in zip(f1, f2)))
```

Note that for unequal number of lines, this one will end at the last line of the file that ends first.

Answer (score 3):

Also, with pure `bash` (notice that this will totally ignore empty lines):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n' GLOBIGNORE='*'
f1=($(< file1))
f2=($(< file2))
i=0
while [ "${f1[${i}]}" ] && [ "${f2[${i}]}" ]
do
    echo "${f1[${i}]}${f2[${i}]}" >> out
    ((i++))
done
while [ "${f1[${i}]}" ]
do
    echo "${f1[${i}]}" >> out
    ((i++))
done
while [ "${f2[${i}]}" ]
do
    echo "${f2[${i}]}" >> out
    ((i++))
done
```

Comment: This is just plain wrong. It doesn't work at all. Either use `mapfile` to read the files into arrays, or use a while loop with two `read` commands, reading from each their fd.

Comment: @geirha You're right, I messed up with the syntax, it's ok now.

Comment: not quite. With the updated code, empty lines will be ignored, and if any line contains glob characters, the line might be replaced with matching filenames. So never use `array=( $(cmd) )` or `array=( $var )`. Use `mapfile` instead.

Comment: @geirha You're right of course, I took care of the glob characters but I left the newline ignored, because in order to do that and in order to make a decent solution out of it it needs to be rewritten. I specified this and 'll leave this version in case it's going to be useful to somebody in the meantime. Thanks for your points so far.

Answer (score 2):

The perl way, easy to understand:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$filename1=$ARGV[0];
$filename2=$ARGV[1];

open(my $fh1, "<", $filename1) or die "cannot open < $filename1: $!";
open(my $fh2, "<", $filename2) or die "cannot open < $filename2: $!";

my @array1;
my @array2;

while (my $line = <$fh1>) {
  chomp $line;
  push @array1, $line;
}
while (my $line = <$fh2>) {
  chomp $line;
  push @array2, $line;
}

for my $i (0 .. $#array1) {
  print @array1[$i].@array2[$i]."\n";
}
```

Start with:

```
./merge file1 file2
```

Output:

```
foobar
icecream
twohundred
```