# how to merge specific text files in a folder?

Tags: merge

I have several text files in a single folder, and I would like to merge only certain sequential files into one long one (where one file comes immediately after the next).

For example, I want to merge all files starting with `test` (so `test1.txt`, `test2.txt`, `test3.txt`, and so on) into one file named `file.out`, like so:

```
Stuff from test1
Stuff from test2
...
Stuff from testN
```

I tried `cat * > file.out`, but that merges everything, which is not what I want. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge files on a line by line basis?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/616166/how-can-i-merge-files-on-a-line-by-line-basis)

Comment: See linked duplicate. It's the job for `paste` command

Comment: If all of your files have a prefix, you can use `cat test* > out.file`.

Comment: @Serg That question seems to be about merging *lines* inside files, not about merging whole files.

Comment: @Nikhil Kalghatgi not ver clear though. "like test1.txt test2.txt etc" needs to be very specific to define what files to merge in what order.

Comment: @JacobVlijm  Well, what text files are made out of ? Lines. And all solutions provided on that question are about merging whole files, so I don't see where you got the idea about merging lines alone.  Of course, I'll wait for OP to clarify and if it's not what they need , but until then my vote will remain.

Comment: @Serg merging `abc` + `def` into `adbecf` is quite different from `abcdef`. Exactly like the accepted answer in the linked dup reflects (the first output). This question asks for the second output.

Comment: @JacobVlijm  well, why don't we wait for OP to clarify. If it's not what they want , i.e. "merge" files, I'll remove my vote. Otherwise, it stays. As it is, the question can be closed for being unclear ,too.

Comment: @KazWolfe   cat test* > out.file worked. this is what i wanted. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

- ways of using wildcards for cat

```
cat test[1-2].txt>out.txt  //matches any character in the set
cat test[!34].txt>out.txt  //matches any character not in the set
cat test?.txt>out.txt  //for a single character
cat test*>out.txt    // for any strings
```